# Timeout when connecting to Amazon RDS (Microsoft SQL Server / PostrgreSQL)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I cannot connect to my fresh new instance of SQL Server Express Edition from the Internet.

```
~$ sudo nc -vz <HOST>.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com 1433
nc: connect to <HOST>.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com port 1433 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

I have already configured AWS security group assigned to this database instance. My inbound and outbound rules are:

```
type:         all trafic
protocol:     all
port range:   all
source:       ::/0
```

Also, everything looks fine on AWS Management Console:

```
DB instance status: available
Pending maintenance: none
Publicly accessible: Yes
```

Locally, I have also disabled my ufw:

```
~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

and iptables:

```
~$ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT && sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT && sudo iptables -F
```

But still, nothing works. (the same happens both to my SQL Server Express Edition and PostgreSQL 9.4.15 on AWS)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your description I assume you want to access your RDS from Internet.

In order to access the RDS ensure this points:

- RDS must be in a **public VPC subnet**.
- RDS must be configured with "**Public accessibility**" = "Yes"
- Security Group should contain **0.0.0.0/0** (IPv4) and **::/0** (IPv6)

Comment: Adding both, 0.0.0.0/4 and ::/0 to Security Group worked. Thanks!